# Is constructor overloading in Character (Wrapper class) possible?

Tags: java, wrapper

The Character class has only one constructor Character (char) , I wondered if there's more constructors of Character class with different parameters, Since all other Wrapper classes have two each.

Comment: Why would you want to overload the constructor of Character?

Comment: You can't add a constructor to other classes at all. Please be more specific in your question, and make sure it's about *one* topic - posts should be on individual problems; if you have two problems, they should be in two posts.

Comment: sorry , I will be careful next time

Comment: Please fix your *current* question to reduce it to a single, clear question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is constructor overloading in Character (Wrapper class) possible?

`Character` is a `final` class. You cannot extend and so overload methods of a `final` class.

A wrapper class is only a class that wraps something : object(s) and or primitive(s) and that generally uses the wrapped under the hood to implement some behaviors.

In case of `Character`, it wraps a `char` value.
Look at the `Character` constructor :

```
public Character(char value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

You can for example see that the `toString()` implementation of `Character` uses it :

```
public String toString() {
    char buf[] = {value};
    return String.valueOf(buf);
}
```

Comment: Boolean is also a final class and my teacher said its constructors can be overloaded i.e Boolean (boolean) and Boolean (string) can be two constructors within the same class with different parameter which is definition of overloading .. am I missing something ?

Comment: No you get it. The class `Boolean` has indeed some overloaded constructors. 
But It is not the case of `Character` that defines a single constructor. So I  said you cannot overload it as you cannot extend a final class.